# How text directed regex engine works internally?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2008

I want to implement simple text directed regular expression engine using MFC in c++.
So can u tell me how text directed regex engine works internally?

For example <.+> this will find a tag in html. How does this work internally?

And also please tell me how to use regular expression in MFC.

Comment: IMO, it would be easier and more reliable to write PCRE glue code instead of writing a CFG parser and its resulting (N)PDA from scratch.

Comment: You could look at an open-source implementation of the `<regex>` standard library functions to see how they do it...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: can u tell me how to use regular expression in mfc?
In my project user will input the regular expression and i have to highlight the matches.

Comment: @ChetanPatil: Just *use*? I thought you wanted to implement your own engine... if you just want to use an existing one, use `<regex>` from the standard library. It's part of MSVC10. There's plenty of documentation on the internet.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: regex in not included in mfc.I am using visual studio 2008.Can i use TR1 Regular Expressions in mfc? I am a newbie and i dont know much about this.

Comment: @ChetanPatil: I'm not sure if it's included, just check for yourself. Failing that, you can use `<boost/regex.hpp>`, which is essentially identical.

Answer (score 4):

This is too complicated to explain in a SO answer.  You either need an advanced textbook on compilers, or access to the source-code of an existing Regex engine.  Fortunately, the OpenJDK source-code is open sourced ... as is the source code for the Apache Harmony version, the Perl version, the Python version and so on.

Some possible text books:

- ["Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools (2nd ed)"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=0321486811&x=0&y=0) by Aho Sethi & Ullman (aka the Dragon book).  The chapter on Lexical Analysis covers regular expressions and their implementation.
- ["Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation (3rd ed)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321455363) by Hopcroft, Motwani &. Ullman.  (Contributed by @Noufal Ibrahim.)

(Earlier editions of both books are available too ... for less money.)

---

> For example `<.+>` this will find tag in html how it works internally.

The glib answer is that it depends on the Regex engine you are using.

Comment: If someone knows a better textbook for regex implementation, please comment.  Thanks.

Comment: I used [this](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Automata-Theory-Languages-Computation/dp/0201441241?tag=duckduckgo-d-20) when I went to college and it was a good book.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, regexps are translated internally into a state machine which is then "executed" based on the textual input. It's a rather involved subject but you can implement a subset of modern regular expressions in a weekend if you want to learn the internals. The books which Stephen C has linked to (especially the dragon book) and any standard discrete mathematics textbook should have details.